# Threshold of anomaly score in scikit-learn's IsolationForest

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, isolation-forest

I'm trying to understand more about how the `contamination` parameter affects the `threshold_` in which a sample is predicted to be an anomaly or not in IsolationForest.

In the code for IsolationForest [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ab93d65/sklearn/ensemble/iforest.py), in `fit()`, the `threshold_` is set by

```
self.threshold_ = -sp.stats.scoreatpercentile(
            -self.decision_function(X), 100. * (1. - self.contamination))
```

Then in `predict()`, a sample is predicted as an anomaly in

```
is_inlier = np.ones(X.shape[0], dtype=int)
is_inlier[self.decision_function(X) <= self.threshold_] = -1
```

I always thought that only negative scores returned by `decision_function` would be predicted as anomaly. But say I have 10 scores `[0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0, -0.1, -0.2, -0.3]`, if I set `contamination = 0.9`, 9 samples with scores between -0.3 and 0.4 would be predicted as anomaly, meaning samples with positive scores are also predicted as anomaly.

Is the calculation of the anomaly scores somehow affected by the `contamination` parameter, such that only up to `contamination` percentage of the scores would be negative? Which in turn would mean `threshold_ = 0`?